# Highcharts/HighcharteR: Stacked Column Bars Get Skinny After 50+ Series in R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am having a problem with skinny bars in a stacked column chart in `highcharter` in R. I have created a repo of the code below and am wondering if someone could help me avoid the issue of having the bars get super skinny when I add more than 49 series to the graph.

Any ideas or work arounds would be greatly appreciated.

As always, thank you in advance.

Best,
Nate

```
library(highcharter)
library(magrittr)
library(viridisLite)

dfmtx<- as.data.frame.matrix(matrix(data = abs(rnorm(n=20*50, mean = 0, sd=1)), ncol = 50))
dfmtx<- dfmtx/rowSums(dfmtx)
df<- data.frame(date=seq.Date(from = as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = Sys.Date(), by="years")[1:20],
                dfmtx, stringsAsFactors = F)



hc<- highcharter::highchart() %>% 
  highcharter::hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  #highcharter::hc_plotOptions(column=list(pointWidth=45, pointPadding=0, groupPadding=0.1, padding=0)) %>%
  highcharter::hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"), series=list(cropThreshold=200)) %>%
  highcharter::hc_xAxis(categories = df$date, title=list(text="Fake Date")) %>%
  highcharter::hc_title(text=paste0("Bars Get Skinny When You Add 50"))

for(i in 2:50){ # Smiles...This Works!
#for(i in 2:51){ # Tears..skinny bars :( 
  the_name<- colnames(df)[i]
  hc<- hc %>%
    highcharter::hc_add_series(name=the_name,
                               data = df[,i],
                               stack = "SameStack") 
  
}
# Pretty colors...why not?
cols<- viridisLite::viridis(n=length(hc$x$hc_opts$series))
cols<- base::substr(cols, 0,7)

hc<- hc %>%
  highcharter::hc_yAxis(title=list(text="Proportion"), max=1) %>%
  highcharter::hc_colors(cols) %>%
  highcharter::hc_legend(align="center") 

hc
```

Comment: Hmm, I can see that you found a solution - cropThreshold in your code. By default, it is set to 50. If there is 50 series or more, the boost module is enabled and columns are 1px width. You need to set series.cropThreshold to a higher value, but... you have already done it in your code :)

Comment: It didn't change anything when I put it in. I'm wondering if there is something else I need to change with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height of the chart using `hc_size()`.

```
for(i in 2:51){ # Tears..skinny bars :( 
  the_name<- colnames(df)[i]
  hc<- hc %>%
    highcharter::hc_add_series(name=the_name,
                               data = df[,i],
                               stack = "SameStack") 
  
}
# Pretty colors...why not?
cols<- viridisLite::viridis(n=length(hc$x$hc_opts$series))
cols<- base::substr(cols, 0,7)

hc<- hc %>%
  highcharter::hc_yAxis(title=list(text="Proportion"), max=1) %>%
  highcharter::hc_colors(cols) %>%
  highcharter::hc_legend(align="center")  %>%
  highcharter::hc_size(height = 800) #Setting chart height to 800.

hc
```